# c++ using the = operator with objects

Tags: c++, object, operators

One operation that continues to confuse me in C++ is how operator= interacts with objects.
I'm not sure what exactly is occurring behind the scenes when executing a program such as this:

```
class ObjectType {
    private:
        int variable;
    public:
        ObjectType(int v) {
            variable = v;
        }
};

int main() {
    ObjectType object1(10);
    ObjectType object2(15);

    object1 = object2;

    return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, it makes all of the member variables in the first object equal to the corresponding member variables in the second object. In this case, the "variable" of `object1` would now equal `15`, but I'm not sure.

Any elaborations would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What did you observe when you ran this? Why not make `ObjectType` have several different types, create two with different values then assign one to the other and see what occurs. If nothing else, this question would benefit from a [mcve] plus you'd learn in the process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ default assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119355/c-default-assignment-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type `object1 = object2;` Here it invokes `=` operator overloaded function, if `operator overloading function` for `assignment operator` is not
defined , then compiler does it for us `by-default` ,the compiler just does a **member-wise copy** from **one object** to **another object**.

Here is basic code :

```
class ObjectType {
        private:
                int variable;
        public:
                ObjectType(int v) {
                        variable = v;
                }
                void operator () (int n1){ /** () operator overloaded function if needed **/
                        variable = n1;
                }
};

int main() {
        ObjectType object1(10);//parameterized constructor will be called  
        ObjectType object2(15);
     /** use case when () operator overloaded function will be called
         ObjecType object1;
         object1(10);// invokes () overloaded function 
     **/

        object1 = object2;/** if = operator overloaded function is not defined then consider default one provided by compiler */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think what OP was asking is related to ``=`` operator. Not sure what the ``()`` operator has to do with this question. ``ObjectType object1(10)`` is just invoking constructor after all.

Comment: @nathanesau I explained both `()` and `=` .

Comment: It is incorrect to say this invokes `operator()`. That would be a plain `object1(10);` statement, for example.

Comment: @chris Got it, I misjudged.